# Dynamic Dojo Axis Labeling

Tags: javascript, dojo, lotus-notes, axis-labels

again i'm stacked on my project

can someone help me on solving dojo's dynamic labeling

i want to get the label name from my view data ...

```
var myLabelFunc = function(value){
                var output:string = "";
                output +=(viewEnt.getColumnValues()[0];
                return output.substr(0, output.length - 1;);
```

and the axis code were

```
                // Add axis
                chart.addAxis("x", { 
                });
                chart.addAxis("y", {
                    labelFunc: myLabelFunc,
                    vertical: true,
                });
```

its show me nothing ... can someone help me solve this ?
Thanks before

Comment: It looks like you are mixing SSJS (viewEnt.getColumnValues()[0]) with CSJS

Answer (score 0):

if I right understood this, you like to pass a value from SSJS to CSJS.

Do the following:

Save the Value you like pass from SSJS in a

```
<xp:inputHidden id="IDXYZ" value=""></xp:inputHidden>
```

Field like this

```
var myLabelFunc:string = function(value){
var output:string = "";
output +=(viewEnt.getColumnValues()[0];
return output.substr(0, output.length - 1;); 
};  

getComponent("IDXYZ").setValue(myLabelFunc );
```

And than read the Value in CSJS over

```
var strXYZ:string=dojo.byId("#{id:IDXYZ}").value);
chart.addAxis("x", { 
            });
            chart.addAxis("y", {
                labelFunc: strXYZ,
                vertical: true,
            });
```